# GMGridview for MonoDevelop and Android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, monodevelop

Does anyone know of something similar to GMGridview for MonoDevelop and Android?

I am looking for something that will allow me to place about 12 to 15 icons/buttons on the Android that I can swipe/scroll back and forth.  I am using MonoDevelop and am very new to Android Development.

I do not necessarily need the drag and drop functionality, but I cannot even find an example of placing many icons on the screen and allowing me to scroll back and forth.

I am struggling with how the layout should be done so any help is appreciated!!

Thank you for any assistance!!!

Answer (score 0):

GridView... ? 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

And I have no idea how is it connected with MonoDevelop.